# PHP - Converting MySQL data into specific format using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

[UPDATE]

I am new to PHP. Before asking the question, I have done many research, but I got noting.
I want to use json_encode but it will bring quotation marks in output, so I ask the question.

Maybe the question is simple. but I just want to have a chance to learn.Thanks.

===================================

There is a table in MySQL server,

```
 col_1       col_2
------------------
2014-08-01    1268
2014-08-01    8900
2014-08-02    32.65
2014-08-03    878
```

I want to use PHP converting the data into the following format in web browsers(without quotation marks):

```
[ [2014-08-01,1268], [2014-08-01,8900],[2014-08-02,32.65],[2014-08-03,878] ]
```

At first, I use the following code, but it doesn't work(including quotation marks). Please give me a hand! thanks.

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT col_1, col_2 from table_A");
$rows = array();
while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    array_push($rows, $line);
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: If you don't want json then don't use json_encode().

Comment: yeah i think the quotes come from json_encode, try switching your last line to `print_r($rows)`

Comment: @JoeT, print_r($rows) can't get the desired format.

Comment: @VMai,I know the quotation marks is from json_encode, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: no but print_r can show you what is in your array.  if you want the desired format you can build it from there.  if i'd done that for you it would've been an answer not a comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the same concatenation with implode and adding the square brackets two times.

First time per line and then over the result:

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT col_1, col_2 from table_A");
$rows = array();
while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = '[' . implode(',', $line) . ']';
}
print '[' . implode(',', $rows) . ']';
```

**Solution with json_encode()**

If you want to use json_encode() and are sure, that there are no double quotes in your result, you could simply use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove the double quotes that you find annoying:

```
print str_replace('"', '', json_encode($rows));
```

**Note:**

If you're new to PHP then you have the great chance to let those mysql_* functions behind you. Learn to use PDO or mysqli right from the start. Both modern APIs have parameterized prepared statements. By using them you get more readable less error prone code and get rid of sql injection by concatenating sql statement strings with user inputs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your explanation is really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
echo "[ ";
while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    if ($i != 0) {
        echo ", ";
    }
    echo $line['col_1'] . "," . $line['col_2'];
    $i++;
}
echo " ]";
```